# Transparent data encryption at column level in sql server

Tags: sql-server

My problem is straightforward. For a customer I need to provide column level transparent data encryption. This means no change in the application code whatsoever not a statement. Oracle provides this. Sql server has 2 modes TDE and column level which is not TDE and requires changes at application level. I was not up to the challenge to provide the customer a Oracle style column level TDE. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't do this unless the application supports it.

Comment: Thought so ... maybe I could think of some clr functions as long I keep it at the database level and application itself remains unchanged

Comment: that won't work -- the functions need to be called.  Clearly it does not meet your specification.  If you can change the code to call the CLR function then you can change the code to use SQL-SERVER encryption support.

Comment: yes ... unless maybe I could use views, encrypt the column in the table (renamed table) create a view with the original table name, make the view decrypt the data. That would be transparent to application but then what I do about inserts. What you think?

Comment: If you can be sure the application has a limited API (specific object names) you may be able to do many things -- your original question did not put that forward as a possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The challenge is definitely possible to resolve because you can create a view with instead of triggers for the insert and update operations. Delete works without adding a trigger. You will need to rework the triggers to suit your needs. I've designed an example:

```
use master
go
create database EncryptedData
go
use EncryptedData
create master key encryption by password='P@ssw0rd!'

create certificate KeyProtection with subject='Key Protection'

create symmetric key ColumnKey 
    with algorithm=AES_256 
    encryption by certificate KeyProtection

create table SecretMessages(Ciphertext varbinary(4000))
go
create view dbo.MessageRecords 
as
select 
    cast(DECRYPTBYKEYAUTOCERT( cert_id('KeyProtection'), null,Ciphertext) as varchar(max)) MessageRecord
from dbo.SecretMessages
go 

open symmetric key ColumnKey decryption by certificate KeyProtection

insert into SecretMessages(Ciphertext) values (ENCRYPTBYKEY(key_guid('ColumnKey'),'Hello world 1'))
insert into SecretMessages(Ciphertext) values (ENCRYPTBYKEY(key_guid('ColumnKey'),'Hello world 2'))
insert into SecretMessages(Ciphertext) values (ENCRYPTBYKEY(key_guid('ColumnKey'),'Hello world 3'))
insert into SecretMessages(Ciphertext) values (ENCRYPTBYKEY(key_guid('ColumnKey'),'Hello world 4'))
insert into SecretMessages(Ciphertext) values (ENCRYPTBYKEY(key_guid('ColumnKey'),'Hello world 5'))
close symmetric key ColumnKey


select * from MessageRecords 
go
create TRIGGER InsMessageRecordsTrg on MessageRecords
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN

open symmetric key ColumnKey decryption by certificate KeyProtection
INSERT INTO SecretMessages
   SELECT (ENCRYPTBYKEY(key_guid('ColumnKey'),MessageRecord))
   FROM inserted
close symmetric key ColumnKey
END
go
create TRIGGER UpdMessageRecordsTrg on MessageRecords
INSTEAD OF update
AS
BEGIN
IF (UPDATE(MessageRecord)) -- If qualification is updated
BEGIN
    open symmetric key ColumnKey decryption by certificate KeyProtection
    update s
        set Ciphertext=ENCRYPTBYKEY(key_guid('ColumnKey'),i.MessageRecord)
    from SecretMessages s
    join deleted d
        on
        cast(DECRYPTBYKEYAUTOCERT( cert_id('KeyProtection'), null,Ciphertext) as varchar(max)) = d.MessageRecord
    cross join inserted i
    close symmetric key ColumnKey
END
end
go
insert into MessageRecords(MessageRecord) values ('Goodbye cruel world')


select * from MessageRecords 

update MessageRecords set MessageRecord='My new message2' where MessageRecord='Hello world 2'

delete from dbo.MessageRecords where MessageRecord='Hello world 3'

select * from MessageRecords 

use master 
go
drop database EncryptedData
```